# Inputting Strings into an ArrayList

Tags: java

I'm having an issue where I can't get values to go into a certain spot of my array lists. I have user input that successfully stores the Strings into variables but I don't know how to put them into a specific cell of the array.

Code:

```
 public void newAccount() {
     firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's your first name?");
     nLastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's your last name?");
     nAddress = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's your current address?");
     nCity= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's your current city?");
     nState = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's your current State?");
     nZipCode = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's your current Zip Code?");
     account.add( accountNumber, firstName);
     account.add( accountNumber, nLastName);
     account.add( accountNumber, nAddress);
     account.add( accountNumber, nCity);
     account.add( accountNumber, nState);
     account.add(accountNumber, nZipCode); 
}
```

Comment: Please consider doing away with the `>` in your posted code as they're distracting and make the code hard to read. Thanks.

Comment: You must mention the data-type of the `account` variable.

Comment: Can you *please* follow a tutorial? (Perhaps one on various Collection types.) This must be about the 10th time this evening this question (or one very similar) has come up ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the variable account is an Arraylist then you're using it wrongly. You are adding only the ZipCode to the arraylist at position account number.

You should create an account object in which the first and last names, zip codes etc go into.

Then put this account object into the Arraylist. That way you'll have an Arraylist populated with account objects.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the following [add method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29) of ArrayList, doing the following allows you to place an entry at a specified index:

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();  
al.add(index, object);
```

Also to note, recall that indexes in Java are 0 based.

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of the `account` variable? If it's an ArrayList, then your design is off as you don't want to add Strings to the ArrayList to represent a single Account object. This is fraught with errors, not the least of which being the risk of adding things out of order. Instead you should create an Account class that has fields for the values that you're currently trying to add to the array list.

```
public class Account {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  // .... etc

  public Account(String firstName, String lastName, .... etc...) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    // .... etc...

  }
```

You could then create an Account object passing in the values that you have above into its constructor.

```
Account newAccount = new Account("John", "Smith", ..... etc...);
```

Then you could have an ArrayList of Account objects, or better represented as `ArrayList<Account>` and add individual Account objects to this list with ease.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: that and `toString()` are left as an exercise for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

As I assume you use and ArrayList... use the second method of `add()` which first parameter accepts the index where the new value will be added

```
account.add(index,value);
```

where is `index` is an integer which will define in what index will be the `value` will be stored in the ArrayList

as `value` can be an Object then you can create a class object and save it to the `value`
for example

```
List<AccountItem> = new ArrayList<AccountItem>();

class AccountItem(){
   public String firstname;
   public String lastname;
}

AccountItem ai = new AccountItem();
ai.firstname= "you";
ai.lastname = "me";

account.add(2,ai); //where i save the new object in index 2
```